# Clicking on any Line of Code causes Plotted Points to Vanish

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 11.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.3.**

Related but non-identical bug present in 10.0-10.4.

Reported to Worfram, Inc as CASE:3926732

---

```
$Version
(* "11.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)" *)

p1 = Plot[{Abs[5 x], -Abs[x/5]}, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}];
zz[{x_, y_}] := Piecewise[{{{3 /5 x -  y + 32/100 , x}, -1/5 Abs[x] <= y <= 
 5 Abs[x]}}, 
    {4/5 x + y + 52/100, x}]
p2 = ListPlot[NestList[zz, {.384, .384}, 212]]
p3 = Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

[image]

Now, if I click on any line of code in the notebook, the points in the second plot vanish from the screen, leaving just the lines.  I imagine that `Show` cannot cope with the extreme difference in `PlotRange` between the two plots.  Nonetheless, I find this bizarre and would welcome an explanation.  By the way, decreasing the third argument of `NestList` to `211` eliminates this behavior, while increasing that argument substantially (say, to `1000`) causes both plots to exhibit this behavior.

Edit: To be more explicit, is this a bug?

Addition: In versions 10.0.2–10.4.1, `Show` does not display the points even at first.

Comment: This title is obscure, misleading, and very unhelpful for anyone trying to search for this information.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  You are right.  I shall change it.,

Comment: I can confirm this behavior as well (same OS, same version here). Not only clicking, but scrolling the MMA window is enough to cause the points in the bottom plot to vanish.

Comment: Behavior is somewhat different when running V11.1 on OS X. I get the plot p2 showing the plotted points for about a second, then the points disappear, leaving only an empty plot. My work-around is similar to John Joseph M. Carrasco's, but I use `pts = NestList[zz, {.384, .384}, 212]; okPts = Select[pts, ManhattanDistance[#, {0, 0}] < 4 &];`

Comment: I am marking this a bug because I think it's been sufficiently confirmed.

Comment: @m_Goldberg  Thanks for confirming the bug on another operating system.  If I add any line of code immediately below `p3 = Show[p1, p2]` and execute the whole block, I too see the points appear momentarily and then disappear.

Comment: Can somebody with access to multiple versions put in the customary header, please?

Comment: @J.M.  I just reported the issue to Wolfram, Inc and was considering what to say in the header.  As I noted in the last line of the question, the bug appears to be different in 10.4, which is the earliest version I have.

Answer (score 3):

I would say this is a bug, but perhaps not so unexpected.

It is indeed about having way too many points out of Range. Fixed, e.g., by selecting only the points you want to plot:

```
    (p1 = Plot[{Abs[5 x], -Abs[x/5]}, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}]) //
       StylePrint;
    zz[{x_, y_}] := Piecewise[{{{3/5 x - y + 32/100, x}, -1/5 Abs[x] <= y <= 
                    5 Abs[x]}}, {4/5 x + y + 52/100, x}];
    (p2 = ListPlot[Select[NestList[zz, {.384, .384}, 212], #.# < 4 &], 
         PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]) // StylePrint;
    p3 = Show[p1, p2]
```

yielding:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the work-around, but it does not really answer my question.

Comment: It looks like a bug that exists happily in `ListPlot`.  At least on my setup, I have the same situation with either: `ListPlot[xxx = 
  Table[{RandomReal[{-1.1, 1.1}, 2], 
    10^20 RandomReal[{-1.1, 1.1}, 2]}, {5}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]` not showing 5 inner points.  Or with  bbgodfrey's  `ListPlot[zoop = NestList[zz, {.384, .384}, 212], 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]` loosing all its points.